# My API call is broken with unknown error. What is the cause of this?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code used to work until a few days ago. I have no idea what updated, maybe new 14.4? But it suddenly stopped working today with a nondescript error and i dont know what is wrong here.

**FetchStockAPIApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FetchStockAPIApp: App {
    @StateObject public var stocks = TFViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(stocks: stocks)
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var stocks : TFViewModel
    
    let isSSL = false
    public var url : String = "http://10.0.0.41:8111/xyz123"
    public var sslurl: String = "https://domain.name:8100/xyz123"
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(stocks.tfstocks!, id: \.recid) { item in
                Text("123")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {stocks.fetchData(apiUrl: isSSL ? sslurl : url)}
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(stocks: TFViewModel())
    }
}
```

**TFDataModel.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TFStock: Codable, Hashable {
    var recid = UUID()
    var symbol: String
    var Close: Double
}


class TFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tfstocks: [TFStock]? = [TFStock]()
    
    func fetchData(apiUrl: String) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: apiUrl) else {
            print("URL is not valid")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            if let data = data {  // data is Optional, so
                // you need to unwrap it
                if let decodedResult = try?
                    JSONDecoder().decode(
                        [TFStock].self, from: data) {
                    // decoding is successful
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // assign the decoded articles to
                        // the state variable
                        self.tfstocks = decodedResult
                    }
                    //print(decodedResult)
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error in API Fetch")")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

remove the XXX from the SSL url to make that API call work in the code.
I would be really grateful if someone could help me out here.

you need to turn isSSL = true to ON so that you use the domain name, since the other IP is just the same API on my local network.

Comment: never ignore DecodingErrors with try?, catch them and print them.

Comment: What’s the difference when value is true or false "stocks.fetchData(apiUrl: isSSL ? url : url)"? You are always passing “url” in both case.

Comment: i forgot sslurl ... updated the code. you need to turn isSSL to ON. @TusharSharma

Comment: Is the API working fine? Did you check it, also add try and catch to catch the error.

Comment: @TusharSharma how do you do this ? i am pretty new to this.

Comment: @Rob yes both the API Urls work fine in browers. locally and the SSL url remotely. It was working like this couple days ago. Now it stopped working. Maybe my code is too flimsy?

Comment: Your Api response doesn’t have any coding key with value “recid”, that’s the error. Verified with postman.

Comment: How come you know it is not working? Is it throwing any error?

Comment: @Rob its just stopping with my Error line "Unknown error in API Fetch" at the bottom of the code.  i guess its having problems parsing the JSON suddenly.

Comment: @TusharSharma i have added recid = UUID() in the data model for that.  XCode doesnt complain about any programming errors. it compiles no errors.

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment ***never ignore DecodingErrors with try?***.

Comment: @AndiAna Yes, then catch the error, look at try and catch and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to read more about `Codable` protocol and what it’s used for. You can refer below link.

https://medium.com/@pleelaprasad/codable-protocols-in-swift-76f8b088c483.

The catch block prints below error for your code.

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "recid", intValue: nil),
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index
> 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "recid", intValue: nil) ("recid").",
> underlyingError: nil)) Error: Unknown error in API Fetch

I have verified the same using postman.

Below is the working solution.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewsss: View {
    @ObservedObject var stocks : TFViewModel
    
    let isSSL = true
    public var url : String = "http://10.0.0.41:8111/xyz123"
    public var sslurl: String = "https://domain.name/xyz123"
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(stocks.tfstocks!, id: \.recid) { item in
                Text(item.symbol)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {stocks.fetchData(apiUrl: isSSL ? sslurl : url)}
    }
}

struct TFStock: Codable, Hashable {
    var recid = UUID()
    var symbol: String
    var Close: Double
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case  symbol, Close
    }
}


class TFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tfstocks: [TFStock]? = [TFStock]()
    
    func fetchData(apiUrl: String) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: apiUrl) else {
            print("URL is not valid")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            if let data = data {  // data is Optional, so
                // you need to unwrap it
                
                do{
                    let decodedResult = try
                        JSONDecoder().decode(
                            [TFStock].self, from: data)
                    // decoding is successful
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // assign the decoded articles to
                        // the state variable
                        self.tfstocks = decodedResult
                    }
                    //print(decodedResult)
                    return
                    
                }catch let error{
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error in API Fetch")")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```